# Laravel Model with and makeHidden

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, model

I'm pulling data on related models into an array. The makeHidden function works well on the Model, however the related model is unaffected.

```
public function show($user)
{
    $model = new User();
    $hidden = $model->allHiddenApiFieldsTemplate();
    $return = $model->with('accounts')->findOrFail($user)->makeHidden(['deleted_at', 'created_at','updated_at'])->toArray();
    return $return;
}
```

Is it possible to hide fields on the related entity using makeHidden? Or another way?

Comment: `makeHidden()` does not work on relations, nor can you use dot notation. Either select the fields you want from the relation, or go through the relations before casting to array.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, `makeHidden` doesn't affect relations. It would have been good it it allowed you to specify attributes in relations as -`makeHidden(['relation.field'])`.

An alternative you can try is:

```
$model->with(['accounts' => function($q) {
    $q->select(['field1', 'field2']);
}])->findOrFail($user)->makeHidden(['deleted_at', 'created_at','updated_at'])->toArray();
```

Not ideal, but it works!

This example uses `select` to select only the fields you require form the relation. Remember to include the primary key used to get the relation.

Answer (score 1):

one way is :

```php
$model->accounts->makeHidden(['deleted_at', 'created_at','updated_at'])
```